# any Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type '() => any'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript

Error: Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type '() => any'.ts(2339)
Error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?ts(2551)
Error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
Here is my data.service.ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
gifs = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getTrendingGifs(){
    return this.http.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=%${environment.giphyApiKey}&limit=50`)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.gifs.next(response.data);
    });
  }
  searchGifs(gifName: string){
    return this.http.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${gifName}&api_key=%${environment.giphyApiKey}&limit=50`)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.gifs.next(response.data);
     });
  }
 getGifs(){
    return this.getGifs.asObservable(); 
  }
}
```

my search.component.ts code

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  search(searchTerm: string){
    if (searchTerm !== ''){
      this.dataService.searchGifs(searchTerm)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log('Search Data', response);
      });
    }

  }
}
```

my gifs.component.ts code

```
import { ThisReceiver } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gifs',
  templateUrl: './gifs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gifs.component.css']
})
export class GifsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  gifs: any[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getTrendingGifs()
    this.subscription = this.dataService.getGifs()
     .subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.gifs = response;
     });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    
  }

}
```

Comment: What you've posted makes no sense. You're not _calling_ that method, but why would it be recursive anyway?

Comment: You have a typo in the `getGifs()` method implementation. You probably meant to do `return this.gifs.asObservable();` to expose the observable part of the subject (though a bit redundant since the subject is already public)

Answer (score 2):

First as @akotech mentioned you have a typo.
Instead of:

```
return this.getGifs.asObservable();
```

You need:

```
return this.gifs.asObservable();
```

Besides: Your approach of retrieving and populating data from server is wrong, you can subscribe to response on component level and then destroy that subscription when component is destroyed to avoid memory leaks.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public getTrendingGifs(){
    return this.http.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=%${environment.giphyApiKey}&limit=50`)
  }

 
public searchGifs(gifName: string){
    return this.http.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${gifName}&api_key=%${environment.giphyApiKey}&limit=50`)
  }

}
```

Component:

```js
import { OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

      search(searchTerm: string){
        if (!searchTerm || searchTerm == '') return;
          this.dataService.searchGifs(searchTerm)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            console.log('Search Data', response);
          });
        
      }

 ngOnDestroy() {
      this.destroy$.next(true);
      this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

And:

```js
import { ThisReceiver } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gifs',
  templateUrl: './gifs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gifs.component.css']
})
export class GifsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  gifs: any[] = [];
  

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.dataService.getTrendingGifs()
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
     .subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.gifs = response;
     });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.destroy$.next(true);
     this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Basically you don't need BehaviorSubject unless you have some other logic requiring it.